# In Skyfall, what is the significance of M's post-mortem gift of a porcelain pug to Bond?

Tags: james-bond, skyfall

At the end of Skyfall, M wills an ugly porcelain pug to James Bond.  When it is suggested to Bond that it was M's way of telling him to take a desk job, Bond affirms that it was just the opposite.  What is the significance of the gift?